# Rendering Color Data to a Window, Win32

Tags: c++, windows

So I am able to create an array of color data (projecting 3d models in case you are wondering), but I need to display them in a Win32 window. I know I could draw it pixel by pixel, but that is really slow. I know that I probably need BitBlt(); I would need it anyway if I am to use double buffering. I have seen how to render a .bmp to the window, but I don't have a .bmp. I guess I could MAKE a .bmp, but I'm going for speed here.

Is there any way to directly (probably not directly, but still quickly) access the pixel data of the hDC? How do graphics libraries do it so quickly?

Comment: Why not take a look at [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). Just search the sources for the parts you need.

Comment: Consider migrating this question to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

To copy your buffer to the DC, you should construct a BITMAPINFO, then use SetDIBitsToDevice() with the screen hDC, the pointer to your buffer and the constructed BITMAPINFO.

You can find a good starting-point for double buffering [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/flickerfree.aspx).

Comment: If the pixel format of array of color data can be expressed in a BITMAPINFO, this is the fastest way to go.  If the color data is in an unusual format, (e.g., floating point values or has weird alignment), you might need to make an intermediate copy.

Answer (score 0):

Render to a MemoryDC (which is quicker for pixel-by-pixel access), then copy that to your window DC.